# How to use Resource Owner Password Credentials with Google OAuth?

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Folks,

I am looking for a functional example of using `com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant`, to **authenticate a user without using the web-based UI**.  Tried the sample provided in the class (replaced https://server.example.com/authorize with https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth), but got invalid_request response.  Is this is the right URL to post to?  Does the request need additional attributes set on it?  Tried setting scope like this, but no luck request.set("scope", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar").  Also tried setting response_type, grant_type,  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is the code (maven project attached as well):

Test.java

```
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenErrorResponse;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant;
import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenResponse;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson.JacksonFactory;
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try {
      ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant request =
          new ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant(
              new NetHttpTransport(), 
              new JacksonFactory(),
              "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth", 
              "<client_id>", 
              "<client_secret>",
              "<user_username>", 
              "<user_password>");
      AccessTokenResponse response = request.execute();
      System.out.println("Access token: " + response.accessToken);
    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
      AccessTokenErrorResponse response = e.response.parseAs(AccessTokenErrorResponse.class);
      System.out.println("Error: " + response.error);
    }
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.acme</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <name>Google OAuth</name>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.api.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1-beta</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Google OAuth2.0 authorization server does not support the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow. If you provide a reason for avoiding the web-based UI, there may be some workarounds available - for example, [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount) within an enterprise setting where your app can act on behalf of the user.

Comment: If Google does not support the Resource Owner Password Credentials then why include a class com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.draft10.AccessTokenRequest.ResourceOwnerPasswordCredentialsGrant?

Comment: @ike_love Based on my reading, Google would include a class with 'Resource Owner Password Credentials' for 2 possible reasons: they made the library standards compliant so that people might use it with other OAuth2 servers, and/or they are eating their own dog food, and using this library in their own Google Sign-In web application.